# Switch between multiple cameras in mozilla Firefox browser

Tags: javascript, firefox, video-streaming, mozilla, navigator

I have multiple cameras connected with my pc.

When I run my HTML page I have the list of camera's when I switch from camera1 to camera2 It is working fine in google chrome browser. But in Firefox I can't able to change the stream of the local video tag.

Here is my working code in chrome.

```
// This is My HTML tag

    <video id="s-video" height="20%" width="15%" class="sub_video" autoplay="autoplay"></video>

// Javascript code

    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video: {deviceId: camera}})
    .then(function(stream) {

        // I also get camera ID Hear in alert
        // svideo is video tag with autoplay enabled

        svideo = document.getElementById('s-video');
        svideo.srcObject = stream;
    });
```

Now, This Code is working in chrome but when I run this page in Firefox browser It is not changing stream even I select a camera from Firefox's permission tab.

My Firefox version is : Firefox Quantum 64.0b11 (64-bit)

OS: Ubuntu 16.04

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you provide a full reproducible example, on JSFiddle or something?  Also, are you stopping the tracks on the original stream first?  I know on Windows, Firefox can handle multiple cameras at the same time.  But, the API it uses for this is different on Ubuntu and maybe that's the issue.

Answer (score 0):

i solve this by changing

```
{ video: { deviceId: 'yourDeviceId' } }
```

to

```
{ video: { deviceId: { exact: 'yourDeviceId' } } }
```

take a look at this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia